# How to make calculations for a complex 3-D conduit shape?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, applications

I'm an electrician running conduit horizontally along a wall at a height of 6 feet off the floor, when I come to a corner of the room. Normally, I would bend a 90-degree elbow and continue level along the adjacent wall, but there are complications.

In the corner, a vertical pipe, 7-inches outside diameter, is running from floor to ceiling. No problem, I would normally change strategies and use a double 45 (45+45) to cut neatly in front of the pipe to the adjacent wall. However, there is a locker with a shelf above it on the adjoining wall that the conduit will need to rise above. The top of the shelf is at 6'10", but I would like to rise to the 7-foot level mark.

And I want to do all of this in only two (2) bends!

I want the shape of the conduit through this corner, from a top view, to appear as a simple 45+45 inside corner, though I realize the hypotenuse of the triangle will actually be stretched out in order to make the 12" rise. Here are some rough sketches of what I mean.

[image: 3D diagram of conduit in corner with pipe obstacle and rise requirement]
[image: Top View diagram of conduit in corner with pipe obstacle]
First Question: If I use 45-degrees for the first bend, How do I calculate the distance from the adjacent wall to make the first bend in order for the conduit to pass just in front of the pipe? (assume the 7-inch pipe is tight up against both walls)

Second Question: How do I calculate the length of my inclined hypotenuse?

Third Question: If I make the first bend at 45-degrees and begin rolling the conduit toward the shelf, the conduit will need to be rotated in my bender out of the plane of the two legs of the first bend to correct the run back to level. How do I calculate the degree of rotation out of plane I should rotate before making the second 45-degree bend?

Fourth Question: Or am I wrong to assume two 45-degree bends can accomplish all of this? If so, what degrees would I need to use?

[Notes: I'm not sure these facts matter, but my conduit is approximately 3/4" in diameter, and the bend radius of the bender is 4-5/16". I do not yet understand how to use radians, but usually working with degrees in regular trigonometry has been close enough for conduit bending.]

Comment: If you add half the diameter of the conduit to the $7''$ diameter of the pipe and double the resulting length you get $7\frac{3}{8}''\times 2=14\frac{3}{4}$,  which gives you the run of a right triangle with $12''$ equal to the rise. That gives you two sides of a right triangle. You want the hypotenuse. So $h=\sqrt{14.75^2+12^2}\approx19''$.

Comment: As far as the final bend, I would secure the first part of the conduit by strapping it down to a horizontal surface and raise the free end until a point $19''$ from the bend is $12''$ above the floor and fix it in that position somehow. Then make the second bend back in the direction of the $19''$ section until the end portion is perpendicular to the floor. That should be close enough so that the piece can be strapped down where it goes.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, I think I know what you mean in your second comment and I like your imagery because it is a good way to envision the problem, but my issue is trying to eyeball that rotation for the second bend. Imagine if I put a chalk line down the length of the conduit and used it as a center-line guide for the first bend and then strapped it down and leaned it over as you prescribe. With a level conduit through the entire corner, I would use the same chalk line again for the center-line of the second bend, but it doesn't work in this case since the entire conduit has already rotated.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, The chalk line is now leaning at....what should be about 45-degrees to the right. If I know for sure it is 45, then can I rotate the bender another 45-degrees off of the chalk line? That might work. I know I can't re-use the center from the chalk line because the conduit would be sticking up at 45-degrees instead of running parallel with the top of the shelf. And I can't rotate a whole 180-degrees and use the side opposite of the chalk line because it would create a rolled offset that shoots directly into the adjacent wall.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, Anyway, the correct rotation is somewhere between the chalk line and the opposite side of it. I think it might be at 90-degrees to the right of the chalk line, but I'd like a mathematical way to calculate this, no matter what the dimensions. Problems like this come up every now and then, and I'm the only electrician I know trying to transition through them with only two bends. It would be cool to be able to do it every time, the first time. I would be showing off, all the time. ;D

Comment: I'll try to think about the problem again tomorrow. This evening I have an engagement.

Comment: I do know that it is a 3D vector problem, Expressing the direction of each vecter in terms of three coordinates and finding the angle between two vectors as $\cos\theta=\dfrac{U\cdot V}{|U|\,|V|}$ but my better half is yelling at me to hurry up so I'm gone for now.

Comment: As you have noticed from your excellent idea of the chalk line, the hard part is not the calculation of the angle of the bend, but in calculating the angle of rotation of the centerline of the bend. It's something I will have to think about (and I recently moved and left my conduit bender and conduit craps behind which would have helped). I have added some tags to your post which might attract more eyes with better ideas of how to attack the rotation angle problem.

Comment: I added a bounty to this question just now. The other night I did a modest experiment, using similar dimensions as the problem above. I used a coffee can for the drain pipe, about 6-1/8" in diameter. Using trig, I came up with 10.5" from each wall to the bends. But I only used a 9" rise onto a concrete block. I experimentally rotated the center lines of the bends approximately 45-degrees apart from each other. What resulted looked like a severely doglegged offset, but it fit near-perfectly into the corner. However, the rotation wasn't quite right. The block end was angled slightly upward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @EthanBolker's excellent diagram, let me label the axes:

$x$-axis, the axis leaving the frame at the bottom middle
$y$-axis, the axis leaving the top right of the frame
$z$-axis, the axis leaving the top left of the frame

Let $(a,0,0)$ and $(0,a,b)$ denote the opposite corners of the box traversed by the conduit, where $a=(2+\sqrt{2})\times\text{Pipe Radius}$ and $b$ is the vertical displacement of the second section of conduit.

Let $\vec{v}_1=\langle 1,0,0\rangle,\quad\vec{v}_2=\langle-a,a,b\rangle,\quad\vec{v}_3=\langle0,1,0\rangle$

Using the formula for the angle between two vectors we can determine that the acute angle for both bends (i.e. the angle between the handle of the conduit bender and the floor) is given by

$$ \theta=\arccos\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\tag{1} $$

But, as noted in the comments, one must still know how much to rotate the centerline of the bend when making the second bend. That amount can be determined by the angle between the normal vectors of the planes containing the two bends.

The two normal vectors are found by taking the cross products $\vec{v}_1\times\vec{v}_2$ and $\vec{v}_1\times\vec{v}_2$.

If my calculations are correct this indicated that the center line of the second bend must be rotated by an angle

$$ \phi=\arccos\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)\tag{2} $$

Clockwise or counter-clockwise? I have no intuition here, best to decide at the moment when the time is at hand.

Comment: You can see these formulas in the openscad program in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are very lucky. With a 12" cubical box, a 7" pipe and a 1" conduit you get just the clearance you need. Two bends, at the same angle: 53.6041 degrees.

ECHO: "cutter rotation", 57.0849

The length of the diagonal part of the conduit is 20.2237" measured along the center of the conduit between the bends.

Between the bends you will have to rotate the conduit in the bender 57.0849 degrees.

[image]

In this [openscad](https://openscad.org/) program you can make the 12" high box shorter along the side wall and longer along the back wall. Here's the picture with a 20" by 9" box.

[image]

The measurements are

```
ECHO: "length", 24.5357
ECHO: "side angle", 68.4808
ECHO: "back angle", 35.3989
ECHO: "bender rotation", 56.2994
```

Here's the program:

```
/*  
openscad program to calculate bending angles and lengths
routing a conduit around a pipe

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460045/how-to-make-calculations-for-a-complex-3-d-conduit-shape 

Adjust dimensions of box so that conduit misses pipe.
Read lengths and angles in console output.

Ethan Bolker
June 2022
*/
// box at the corner  
height = 12 ;
boxback  = 20;    // along back wall
boxside  = 9;   // along side wall
pipe   = 7;    // pipe diameter
conduit = 1;   // conduit diameter

// points on conduit
// just outside the box
sidecorner = [boxside+conduit/2,conduit/2, conduit/2];
backcorner = [conduit/2,boxback+conduit/2, height-conduit/2];
// along the walls
sidewall = [1.2*boxside+conduit/2,conduit/2, conduit/2];
backwall = [conduit/2,1.2*boxback+conduit/2, height-conduit/2];
// conduit segments
diagonalconduit = backcorner - sidecorner;
sideconduit     = sidecorner-sidewall;
backconduit     = backwall - backcorner;

// normal vectors to conduit planes at corners 
// to determine rotation in bender
sidenormal = cross(sideconduit, diagonalconduit);
backnormal = cross(diagonalconduit, backconduit);

// output to console
echo("length", norm(diagonalconduit));
echo("side angle", angle(sideconduit, diagonalconduit));
echo("back angle", angle(backconduit, diagonalconduit)); 
echo("bender rotation", angle(backnormal,sidenormal));

// illustration
// draw the pipe
translate([pipe/2,pipe/2, 0])
cylinder(h=height, d=pipe,$fn=32);

// draw the conduit segment by segment
color("black",1.0) {
  hull(){point(sidecorner);point(backcorner);}
  hull(){point(sidecorner);point(sidewall);}
  hull(){point(backcorner);point(backwall);}
}

//draw the box
color("green",0.2)
cube([boxside, boxback, height] );

module point(position){
    translate(position)
    sphere(d=conduit,$fn=32 );
}


function angle (a,b)=atan2(norm(cross(a,b)),a*b);
```

Nice problem.

Comment: +1 The linked program is very nice.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the CAD freeware! I'll need to play around with it. For the bounty, I'm looking for steps on how to calculate not only this problem but similar situations with varying dimensions.

Comment: @Nicknamednick If you send me email (check by SE profile) I will send you the openscad code. You can vary the height, width and length of the box.

Comment: @EthanBolker, thanks! I sent you an email and included some pictures of an experiment I made with the bender and a similar obstacle course.